# How To send image to google Chat space from google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-chat, google-chat-api

I have a chat space where I need to send daily alerts of different computations performed. The alert can be a simple table or a plot (matplotlib Figure). From some research, I think its not possible to send local image (buffer) directly to chat space. So I'm storing the alert image in a google cloud storage bucket (temporarily) and plan to send image by imageUrl as shown in the message_body below.

```
# Request Body
message_body = {
              "cards": [
                  {
                      "header": {
                          "title": "Title",
                          "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                      },
                      "sections": [
                          {
                            "header": "TEST IMAGE",
                            "widgets": [
                                {
                                "image": {
                                    "imageUrl": # Url of image inside bucket
                                            }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
```

In *imageURL* I have used both

- Authenticated url (format: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/project-id/test-image.png")
- [Signed Url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

**What I have tried**

**Using Webhook:**

```
webhook_url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/..."
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(message_body), headers=headers)
```

**Using REST API**
After configuring Chat API with my app

```
request = chat.spaces().messages().create(parent=f'spaces/space_name',body=message_body)
result = request.execute()
```

Both method sends an empty card on Google chat space without image.
But if I replace the cloud storage urls with

```
"imageUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660846194677-96299f2713f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyOHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
"imageUrl": "https://any/image/hosting/site"
```

Both method works perfectly (sends a card with image in it).

The Data might be sensitive so I don't want it to go out on any image hosting platform.